# What does the operator ! mean in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

What does the "!" operator means in F#?

For example it is here

```
    let x = !a * !b
    yield x
```

or here

```
    c := !c + 1.0
```

Comment: Although symbolic operators are difficult to Google, searching for "f-sharp operators" brings up [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) which has the answer at the top of the page.

Comment: The reason you are getting down votes is that you did not show any effort here to resolve your problem. You did not explain that it is hard to Google for `!`, you did not show links to any pages you searched, etc. We don't mind helping others, but we do not like to do the work for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's used to dereference a cell.  Check this [page.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

It's  *! (bang)* operator
as [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx) document says,

> - Dereferences a reference cell.
> - After a keyword, indicates a modified version of the keyword's    behavior as controlled by a workflow.